# How can use Codeigniter my_model class for udate with multiple where condetion?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, my-model-jami

Iam used codeigniter my_model class for update my table datas.

Actulay i need the query is

```
`UPDATE `pay_project` SET `awarded` = '129' WHERE `pay_id` = 1 and `status` ='y'
```

For this purpose am tried the codeignter my_model function update

```
$this->pay_project_model->update_by(array('pay_id'=>1,'status'=>'y'),$updateJob);
```

But the code is not working, if am trying the update() instead of update_by() at that time its showing like this

```
`UPDATE `pay_project` SET `awarded` = '129' WHERE 'id'=array()
```

Please help me to solve this ? Also am trying with update_many(), same is not working..

The model using is 
https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Codeigniter My_model class, then you need to change your model like this to work the update_by() function

```
class Pay_project_model extends MY_Model {
protected $table='pay_project';
function update_by($where = array(),$data=array())
 {
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->update($this->table,$data);
        return $query;
  }
}
```

In My_model class there is not a default option to update the class by multiple where conditions, So you need to write update_by() function. Simple copy paste the function inside your class, and this will be work perfectly.

Comment: Is this requore to add this $table variable in the model ? For my_model ithink its work directly form name.. Anyway its worked for me..

Answer (score 3):

Try this Active Records it'll let you know what you were doing along with query

```
function update($data = array(), $where = '') {
    $where = array('pay_id'=>1,'status'=>'y');
    $data = array('awarded' => '129');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $res = $this->db->update($this->main_table, $data);
    $rs = $this->db->affected_rows();
    return $rs;
}
```

Comment: Now its look Active Records query.

Comment: Thanks for the query, but i need the my_model class funciton ( https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model ) . this is for Ci_model class right ?

Comment: But you didn't specified it within your question edit your tags

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query you need in your model function.

```
class my_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /*Model function*/
    function update_by($condition = array(),$updateJob=array())
    {
        if($condition && $updateJob)
        {
            $this->db->where($condition);
            $this->db->update('pay_project', $updateJob );
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can use your existing code from controller for your desired purpose.

```
$updateJob = ['awarded' => '129'];
$this->pay_project_model->update_by(array('pay_id'=>1,'status'=>'y'), $updateJob);
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, but i need the my_model class funciton ( https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model ) . this is for Ci_model class right ?

Comment: You can see i have added my_model class example here.

Comment: You can call `$this->pay_project_model->update_by(array('pay_id'=>1,'status'=>'y'),$updateJob);` from the controller you want to perform the action.

Comment: am used that too, but its geting the query is like `UPDATE `pay_project` SET `awarded` = '129' WHERE 'id'=array()

Comment: I have updated the function. It is working properly in my code. If you are still not getting the solution then please post your code for controller and model files.

Comment: From where are you calling `$this->pay_project_model->update_by(array('pay_id'=>1,'status'=>'y'),$updateJob);` ? 
From controller ?

Answer (score 2):

use this codeigniter active records for doing database operations

```
$data = array(
           'awarded' => '129'
        );
$where = array(
          'pay_id'=>1,
          'status'=>'y'
         );

$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update('pay_project', $data);
```

For documentation refer this link
  [codeigniter active records update](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update)

Comment: Thanks for the query, but i need the my_model class funciton ( https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model ) . this is for Ci_model class right ?

Comment: Yes.I think its better to use the inbuilt model class for simple works like this .

Comment: @AyonaJose The documentation for my_model says that its an extension for of ci_model so this will be compatable. I believe it will work just fine. Just give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$query = $this->db->query("UPDATE pay_project SET awarded = '129' WHERE pay_id = '1' and status ='y' ");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```